# Geo-location Specific Tweet Collection from Spatial Dataframe

Tags: r, string, twitter

I am using `twitteR` package to extract some geo-located tweets. Here are my spatial locations:

```
aa1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
latitude longitude
30.27332 -97.74344
                   30.23302 -97.70345
                   30.27232 -96.70333
                   30.24332 -97.74342
                   30.27332 -97.89341
                   30.27342 -97.45349
                   ")
aa1
latitude longitude
30.27332 -97.74344
30.23302 -97.70345
30.27232 -96.70333
30.24332 -97.74342
30.27332 -97.89341
30.27342 -97.45349
```

I want to run a simple function to auto-extract tweets. As `searchTwitter` function works on string, I am not able to extract the tweets. Here's my code:

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(RCurl)

api_key <- ".."  
api_secret <- ".."  
access_token <- ".."  
access_token_secret <- ".."  
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)

for (i in 1:length(aa1[,1])){
  tweets = searchTwitter('geocode:aa1[,1], aa1[,2], 20km',  n=10)
  dat <- data.frame(length(tweets))
  aa1[i,3] <- dat
}
```

`geocode:aa1[,1], aa1[,2], 20km` is not working as it's in string format. Is there a way to override `string/function` problem?

Comment: My reading of the docs at [cranr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf) suggest the geocode is not in the search string but rather is a geocode parameter. something like:

`searchTwitter('#tag ', geoCode=paste0(aa1[i,1], ',', aa1[i,2], ',', "20km"))`

The docs note that the first search parameter is always required

Comment: @epi99 you answer is correct, but the parameter geocode is lower case all the way: `searchTwitter('#tag ', geocode=paste0(aa1[i,1], ',', aa1[i,2], ',', "20km"))` should work.